# Running Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-line, jupyter

Running on Windows 10.  New to Python.  Just installed `python 3` and installed `jupyter` via `pip`.  I cannot get `jupyter notebook` to run.  Everything is under this path: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>`

I figured I could just type `jupyter notebook` in the prompt but it's not working. Do I have to install `Anaconda` to get this to run or something?

Comment: What is the error you're getting when running `jupyter notebook`?

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have Python in your system variables.

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>
2. Click Advanced System Settings (you need admin rights here)
3. Click Environment Variables
4. In the lower part where it says "System Variables" click on the line that says `PATH` and then on "Edit"
5. Append to that sequence of paths your Python path where the `python.exe` and also the `jupyter.exe` are located (which is in the `/Scripts` subfolder of your Python directory). Separate the paths with a semicolon, do not add spaces or trailing slashes, like so:

   `C:\path1;C\path2\subfolder;D:\path3\subfolder\subsubfolder`
6. Click OK and you're done. Now Python and `jupyter` should work from the command line

Comment: It's still not working but at least seems like it's trying, it shows a bunch of paths and at the end OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.   These are the paths I have in Environment Variables.....C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts

Comment: The paths look about right. Can you paste the complete error here please?

Comment: C:\Users\zj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\zj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-

Comment: packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 31, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled[0])
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "c:\users\zj\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OError: [WinError 126] The specif